# Filter dataGridView using a TextBox that ignores Case Sensitivity

Tags: c#

I am filtering my dataGridView using a text box. It does filter as intended but, I am wanting it to ignore case sensitivity. Here is what I have:

```
 var filter = db.Profiles.Local.Where(x =>x.FirstName.Contains(txtSearchName.Text));

 profileBindingSource.DataSource = filter.ToList();

 dataGridProfiles.Refresh();
```

How do I modify this so that it will ignore case sensitivity?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how I apply that to the code I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I'm just giving you the answer from [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

```
var filter = db.Profiles.Local.Where(x => 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(
    x.FirstName, txtSearchName.Text, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

[MSDN - CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7zs7dcf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This does not work as intended. I want to find where it contains whatever I type with it ignoring case sensitivity. Here I will have to type the whole name for it to filter. For example, if i typed in lowercase c, I want it to return any name that contains the letter "c".

Comment: Using "StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase does not work with Contains. You get an error that says "No overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments.

Comment: Works perfectly, exactly how i wanted. Thank you very much :)